# Cross browser audio input for PHP web forms

Tags: javascript

I've seen alot of information on the use of HTML5 and webkit speech to record audio as text input for a web form.  The problem is that only works in the desktop version of Chrome.  Does anyone know of a javascript library or some other resource that works specifically with mobile devices in mind as well as other desktop browsers?  The below code does not work on the mobile edition of chrome.

```
<input type="text" x-webkit-speech />
```

Comment: That's really a browser feature issue that you cannot "circumvent" (or in this case, invent), even with some JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, I've found the keyboard on Android tablets have an Audio key on the keyboard that allows the same function.  You must first click in the form element and then choose the microphone key on the keyboard but its essentially the same thing.  The only different is that you cannot immediately launch the microphone directly from a webkit speech enabled form element.  Not a big deal in retrospect.